# local variable may point to deallocated memory

Tags: c, matrix, memory, malloc, clion

i have a struct in the header (ex3.h)

```
typedef struct matrix {
    double **data;
    size_t n_rows;
    size_t n_columns;
} matrix;
```

in the c file i have function "create_matrix" and another function slice
and i'm getting warning **"local variable may point to deallocated memory"** in some places.. i mark them as "--->" in comments

```
#include <stdlib.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include "ex3.h"
#define DEBUG
matrix *create_matrix (size_t n_rows, size_t n_columns)
{
  matrix *mat = malloc (sizeof (matrix));
  if (!mat)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, POINTER_ERROR);
      return NULL;
    }
  if (n_rows == ZERO || n_columns == ZERO)
    { mat->data = NULL, mat->n_rows = ZERO, mat->n_columns = ZERO; }
  else
    {
      {
        double **mat_data = malloc (n_rows * sizeof (double *));
        if (!mat_data)
          {
            free (mat);
            fprintf (stderr, POINTER_ERROR);
            return NULL;
          }
        for (int i = ZERO; i < n_rows; i++)
          {
            mat_data[i] = malloc (n_columns * sizeof (double));
            if (!mat_data[i])
              {
                for (int k = ZERO; k < i; k++)
                  {
                    free (mat_data[k]);
                  }
                free (mat_data), free (mat);
                fprintf (stderr, POINTER_ERROR);
                return NULL;
              }
            else
              {
                for (int j = ZERO; j < n_columns; j++)
                  {
                    mat_data[i][j] = (double) ZERO;

                  }
              }
          }
        mat->data = mat_data, mat->n_rows = n_rows, mat->n_columns = n_columns;

      }
    }
  return mat;
}

matrix *slice (matrix *mat, size_t row_start,
               size_t row_end, size_t col_start, size_t col_end)
{
 "some condions..."
    {
      matrix *m = create_matrix (ZERO, ZERO); //nul matrix
      if (!m) "<---"
        {
          return NULL;
        }
      return m; "<---"
    }
  else
    {
      size_t row = row_end - row_start, col = col_end - col_start;
      matrix *new_mat = create_matrix (row, col);
      if (!new_mat)"<---"
        {
          return NULL;
        }
      for (int i = ZERO; i < row; i++)
        {
          for (int j = ZERO; j < col; j++)
            {
           "--->"   (new_mat->data)[i][j] = mat->data[i + row_start][j + col_start];
            }
        }
      return new_mat; "<---"
    }
}
```

i made a few conditions that insure i'm not try to go to a space in the memory place that is not part of my matrix, so why clion still make a warning
thanks for trying to help!

Comment: At first glance, your code appears to be returning either allocated space or a null pointer and to be checking for a null pointer at appropriate places. That suggests the tool reporting the error may be wrong or the source code you are using it with may differ from what you have posted. Edit the question to contain a [mre]. Put all the code in one sequence, not separate blocks, so that readers do not have to edit the pieces together to compile them, and include all necessary statements in the source code, such as `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>`…

Comment: … Then reduce the code; remove statements that are not necessary to reproduce the problem, such as some of the `if`/`else` clauses that do not have the error. Then ensure the code you paste here is exactly the code that gets the message. Also, state the name and version number of the tool that is reporting the error message. That is not CLion; CLion is an Integrated Development Environment. It is like a toolbox that can contain various tools, and it is one of those tools, not CLion, reporting the error. The tool may be a compiler or some code checker.

Comment: Also, you cannot use \*\* inside code style to mark bold text. Inside a code segment, the usual markup characters are disabled because they might appears as part of source code. You can add comments to the source code to show where the error messages appear, such as `// The following line gets an error message.`.

Comment: new_mat size : row_end-row_start+1 idem for columns

Comment: @ptitXav it's new row = [start, end)

Comment: Even if one dimension is zero it should be zero size array

Comment: @0 Disagree with "if one dimension is zero it should be zero size array".  Really depends on larger coding goals.

Comment: ZurBinyamini, `[start, end)` (and not `[start, end]`) is not intuitive based on parameter names.  A comment in code is warranted.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Half-open intervals are the natural order of the world. If a half-open interval contains n elements, then the interval with the endpoints doubled has 2n elements (e.g., [10, 20) has 10, and [20, 40) has 2•10=20). In contrast, a closed interval needs adjustment ([10, 20] has 11, and [20, 40] has 2•11−1, which is perverse and abhorrent to civilized people). So half-open intervals are intuitive, and closed intervals are alien.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Disagree that one is the natural order of the world and the other is perverse and abhorrent is the sole valid viewpoint.  e.g. `[0...UIN_MAX], [INT_MIN...INT_MAX]`, [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution), scan_set `[a-z]`,  "last element of an array" vs. "one past". It is a common source of mis-understanding and hence a comment is still warranted.  I agree the half-open interval is preferable but not with names like `start, end`, which sound like a close interval.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it another way. Instead plenty of allocations I would use only one. Instead of negative tests (ie is something is wrong) I would use positive tests and have only one return point from the function.

```
typedef struct matrix {
    size_t n_rows;
    size_t n_columns;
    double data[];
} matrix;

matrix *allocate(size_t r, size_t c)
{
    matrix *m = malloc(sizeof(*m) + r * c * sizeof(m -> data[0]));
    if(m)
    {
        m -> n_rows = r;
        m -> n_columns = c;
    }
    return m;
}

matrix *slice(matrix *m, size_t sr, size_t er, size_t sc, size_t ec)
{
    matrix *result = NULL;
    size_t lc = ec - sc, lr = er - sr;
    if(m && m -> n_rows > er && m -> n_rows > sr && sr <= er && m -> n_columns > ec && m -> n_columns > sc && sc <= ec)
    {
        result = allocate(lr, lc);
        if(result)
        {
            double (*dest)[lc] = &result -> data;
            double (*src)[m -> n_columns] = &m -> data;

            result -> n_rows = lr;
            result -> n_columns = lc;
            for(size_t row = 0; row < lr; row ++)
            {
                memcpy(dest[row], &src[sr + row][sc], lc * sizeof(m -> data[0]));
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about : double (*dest)[lc] = &result-> data;  ?

Comment: @PtitXav Yes I am sure

Comment: any dv explanation?

Comment: This post does not answer the question (why is the warning issued) and breaks the semantics of the code (the original code supports zero-size matrices; when either dimension is zero, the routine does not return a null pointer but returns a pointer to a structure describing an empty matrix, and this is apparently deliberate based on the code dedicated to it).

Comment: Additional minor notes: `m -> n_rows > er && m -> n_rows > sr && sr < er` is redundant, as `m->n_rows > er && sr < er` implies `m->n_rows > sr`.  `memcpy(dest[row], &src[sr + row][sc], lc * sizeof(m -> data[0])` can be `memcpy(dest[row], &src[src + row][sc], sizeof dest[row])`. `size_t lc = ec - sc, lr = er - sr;` declares identifiers outside the scope where they are needed; they can be inside the `if`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `memcpy(dest[row], &src[sr + row][sc], lc * sizeof(m -> data[0])`` can be `memcpy(dest[row], &src[src + row][sc], sizeof dest[row])` same code wil be generated and for **me** is easier to read (you do not have to find declaration of `dest`. First one was intentional to show my *intentions*

Comment: @EricPostpischil zero size array - amended the answer

Comment: Even if one dimension is zero it should be zero size array